# How to configure an ElasticSearch index to use nested types by default using NEST

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, json.net, nest

I am using Elasticsearch to index complex hierarchical objects which are derived from a very complex object model (over 1000 objects in multiple inheritance hierarchies). However. all objects are derived from a single base class.

The objects to index. are built dynamically using dictionaries in C# and the JsonExtensionData attribute from JSON.NET for serializing dictionaries to JSON as I don't know in advance the structure of the object which is being indexed as it is derived from a third party system.

I need to ensure that objects are indexed using nested types by default regardless of the actual structure or type of object.

I've found some information on this on StackOverflow which suggested it can be done using dynamic templates but I could not find a concrete example of how this can be done.

So far I've tried to define a map using the fluent interface like this

```
client.Map<Entity>(m => m
        .MapFromAttributes()
        .DynamicTemplates(d => d
            .Add(t => t
                .Name("nested")
                .Mapping(map => map.NestedObject<Entity>(s => s.MapFromAttributes().IncludeInParent(true))))));
```

I'm indexing the objects as follows

```
var response = client.Index<Entity>(entity, i => i.Index(index).Type(subType));
```

Where Entity is the base class on which all the objects are based and subType is a string representation of the real underlying type of the root object being indexed.

But when I retrieve the mapping, the sub-object mappings are still all identified as ObjectMapping not NestedObjectMapping.

Would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I can't use the ElasticProperty attribute for this by the way as the object model is mostly defined through generic <string,object>dictionaries and is not strongly typed. (The reason for this is complex but it is to do with how the data is returned from the 3rd party system).

Comment: Can you add response of localhost:9200/index/{subType}/_mapping ?